# How to replace my CustomView with different Xib's

Tags: cocoa, xcode4.5, xib, nsview, custom-view

I placed one customView on my window in .xib file.
In that CustomView I have to load different views(xibs consist of CustomViews) from different xib files.

I am able to display any of those xib's for first time, but when I want to display any other than that as my second choose its getting overlapping on previous view.

I am currently using 
       [view addSubview:myNewView];

Actually I have to use
       [mySubview replaceSubview:-------- with:myNewView];
In these I am not getting what to give as a parameter in 'replaceSubView'.

simply to say I want to know whats the xib is currently loading in my view.
Can any one please help in solving these issue.

Thank u in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

Might help you to understand what you're actually doing there:

**[Introduction to View Programming Guide for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)**